# How to migrate ngx-swiper-wrapper to swiper?

Tags: angular, swiper.js, ngx-swiper-wrapper

I am working with a project which is using `ngx-swiper-wrapper`. My version has a dependency to a version of swiper which has vulnerabilities.
I read in the `ngx-swiper-wrapper` project that since `swiper@6.4.0` I have support for angular and there is no need to use the wrapper library. (`swiper@6.5.1` is clean of vulnerabilities so this is the version I want to reach, now I am using 5.3.7)

So my aim here is to delete the `ngx-swiper-wrapper` and start using only `swiper`. Is there a way that I can migrate this automatically? or maybe some steps with counterpart functions between both libraries or some advice I have to be aware of while migrating manually?

I have not try anything yet.